# Что происходит при вызове конструктора (точнее в вопросе)?

Tags: c++, ооп

Допустим, у меня есть какая-нибудь функция, в которой есть такая строчка: `char test = std::string("T").at(0);`. Я создал переменную типа `char`, она уничтожится как только выйдем из функции. А вот память, которую я выделил с помощью `std::string("T")`, она сразу же удалится, после этой строчки, или также будет до выхода из функции "висеть" в памяти? Мы вроде как конструктор вызвали, значит память выделили, но вот  никуда не записали её, поэтому я не уверен, как это будет работать.

Comment: связанный раздел на [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Созданная строка является временным объектом, существующим до конца вычисления выражения, в котором он участвует. После вызова at(0) и присвоения результата в test, временный объект будет уничтожен.